# Is there a way to reload/reset a form from a different form?

Tags: vb.net

Im making a game witch there is this play again option when you loss then i just use me.hide form2.show but after that nothing works anymore yeah the form pop ups but it does literally nothing so Im wondering to reset or reload those form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do as K3rnel31 said, but also check in the Options of the program (Menu bar -> Project> -Project Name- Properties) Then click the 'Shutdown Mode' And change the drop down menu to when last form closes. It's in the Application tab (Should be the first one)

Answer (score 0):

```
On Form 1 ==>
 dim f2 as new form2 'user clicks Start Game
 f2.show
 me.close()

On Form 2 ==> 'whene the game is over or something
dim f3 as new form3 
f3.show()
me.close

On form3 ' score... Game over try again ? user clicks yes
dim f2 as new form2 
f2.show
me.close
```

Comment: Hi it works but when i put those in every forms it says error i got a screenshot here: http://i44.tinypic.com/20gxhe8.png

Comment: @user2993018 the 'new' you must use it whene you want to reset the form if you have to reset just the form for the new game not all both

Comment: I dont get what you mean sorry

Comment: tell me what is the form what countains the game ? (what must be reset)

Comment: Well its kinda form 1 has a startgame option when press it goes to form 2 which is the game then to form 3 are the score summaries with playagain option then goes again to form 2 to play again its kinda loop around

Comment: @user2993018 ok recheck the answer if does not reslove your problem so you have something wrong

Comment: 'On GoTo' and 'On GoSub' statements are no longer supported. I get this on the On code

Comment: @user2993018 if you can upload your code something i can help you

Comment: @user2993018 try to use me.Hide() instead of Me.close()

Comment: You don't need the `On Form <No.> ==>`