# How to reload/refresh/reset a form in vb.net 2008

Tags: vb.net

Hi, I got this game it got multiple form so lets say Form1 is the main menu then the player presses start game. It goes to Form2 which is the game after game is finish it goes to Form3 then there will be a play again option where, it goes to the game again. I already use

```
Dim f2 As New Form2
```

yeah it goes to the game but the game very weird and unstable I feel like some of the code didn't reset so how do I do this?

Comment: it sounds that you have not sloved your problem

Comment: you will get the same answers as the mine you have to post all your code and let me help you

Comment: the problem is not on the reset maybe other

Comment: @K3nel31 It's all fixed now my bad didn't see the me.close() I kept doing me.hide() Thank very much!

Comment: can you so turn my answer as correct http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20016330/is-there-a-way-to-reload-reset-a-form-from-a-different-form/20018061?noredirect=1#comment29812343_20018061

Comment: @K3rnel31 I cant it says requires 15 points to upvote I only have 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim f2 As New Form2
Form2.Show()
Me.Close()
```

That should reset Form1

```
Dim f3 As New Form3
Form3.Show()
Me.Close()
```

That will reset Form2

```
Dim f1 As New Form1
Form1.Show()
Me.Close()
```

That will reset Form3 and return to Form1

Comment: @K3rnel31 How isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Set your application properties to :

Shutdown Mode : When Last Form Closes

When you move from Form1 to From2, just hide form1 using

```
Form1.Hide()
```

Then in form2.load event, just close Form1

```
Form1.close()
```